# How to interpret the $@ symbol in a makefile loop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools

In a makefile I have this piece of code

```
all clean dep depend print:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do \
        if $(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $$dir $@; then \
            true; \
        else \
            exit 1; \
        fi; \
    done
```

What is the meaning of $@ in the line

```
if $(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $$dir $@; then \
```

I know this is an Automatic Variable that matches the file name of the target of the rule. Here the target appears to be a command like cancel:

```
cancell:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Comment: `I know this is an Automatic Variable that matches the file name of the target of the rule` So what's the question then? It **does** expand into the rule target name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Automatic variable that expands to the name of the target which caused the recipe to run.   In your case, if you type `make all`, it expands to `all`.   If you type `make all clean`, it will run the recipes twice -- the first time, `$@` will expand to `all`, and the second time it will expand to `clean`.

See documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)